# Nested routes using drf-extensions are not documented in API docs

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, python-2.x, drf-extensions

I'm writing API in DRF and had need to add nested routes. 
Since `drf-extensions` are specified in official documentation I tend to use this package and it seemed to be working, but the documentation generated by Django Rest Framework doesn't include nested Viewset(route).

The documentation is generated using `include_docs_urls` from `rest_framework.documentation`

I would really like to have my nested endpoint described in generated documentation.
Is it possible?

djangorestframework==3.9.0

drf-extensions==0.5.0

Python2.7

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Yes, apparently it was issue caused by me.
Something like wrong permissions I guess, so it should generate it properly (as it is now )